# JOGL OpenGL 4.2 bindings missing?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I'm learning OpenGL and since I'd like stuff to be able to run on the web as untrusted code without explicit user set privileges I'm figuring JOGL is my only solid option, or are there other alternatives?  Anyway, it looks like JOGL only supports OpenGL 3.x for the moment, how can I get 4.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JOGL 2.0](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/) already supports OpenGL 4.x and has supported OpenGL 3.x for years. JOGL is a part of the [JogAmp](http://jogamp.org) set of APIs including JOCL (Java binding for OpenCL), JOAL (Java binding for OpenAL) and a Java binding for OpenMAX API. It supports both OpenGL and OpenGL ES in an homogeneous way even on Linux ARM and Android as you can see [here](http://jausoft.com/blog/2011/08/17/jogl-embedded-device-status-p1/) and [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VHxtVT4tWjM).

Comment: I've checked JOGL 2.0 and it does not yet have support for OpenGL 4.2. However it is expected that it may get added sometime in the future.

Comment: As far as I know, only some extensions of OpenGL 4.2 are missing but they will be added soon.